# Unknown column 'clientproj0_.clienthours_id' in 'field list (JPA @OneToMany(mappedBy = "clienthours"))

Tags: java, jpa, view, relationship, many-to-one

I have 2 views

> "client_hours_view"

**(ClientHoursInfo.java)** and

> "client_project_hours_view"

**(ClientProjectHoursInfo.java)**

The first view already existed in the application and :
Retrieves all the clients in the work hours in total

The second view is the new pne and:
Retrieves all the clients with a list of projects for each client and their hours

Anyways, I just want to find a way to retrieve all the clients (first view) with a list of their respective projects (second view), and the best I could figure out is by adding a field list in the **ClientHoursInfo.java** :
**private List clientProjectList** which will contain a list of projects for each client.

I have extracted below the code to show only the relation needed against these 2 views
However I am not able to succesfully run it, since it is showing the below error in the console.

```
Unknown column 'clientproj0_.clienthours_id'
```

I would like to get guidance to solve this or find a different approach to meet the requirement.

---

### **ClientHoursInfo.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "client_hours_view")
public class ClientHoursInfo {

@Id
@Column(name = "unique_id")
private String uniqueId;

private Long id;

private String client;

@Column(name = "week_ending")
private String weekEnding;

@Column(name = "total_hours")
private Double totalHours;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "clienthours")
private List<ClientProjectHoursInfo> clientProjectList;

}
```

---

### **ClientProjectHoursInfo.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "client_project_hours_view")
public class ClientProjectHoursInfo {

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Employee clienthours;

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private String Id;

}
```

---

### **FinanceManagerReports.java**

```
clientHours = clientHoursInfoViewRepository.findByWeekEndingBetween(from, to);
for (ClientHoursInfo clientHoursInfo : clientHours) {
clientProjectHours = clientProjectHoursInfoViewRepository
.findByClientIdAndWeekEnding(clientHoursInfo.getId(), clientHoursInfo.getWeekEnding());
clientHoursInfo.setClientProjectList(clientProjectHours);
}
```

---

### **Error Console**

```
[2019-10-02 17:21:57.887] boot - 9656 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-3] --- SqlExceptionHelper: Unknown column 'clientproj0_.clienthours_id' in 'field list'
[2019-10-02 17:21:57.888] boot - 9656 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-3] --- [dispatcherServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'clientproj0_.clienthours_id' in 'field list'
```

Comment: Probably you need to use `@JoinColumn(name = "whatever_it_really_is")` for the `@ManyToOne`. Right now JPA has assigned the name to be `clienthours_id` but it is probably something else in the view.